# Verb tense for something must be completed by the current moment

Tags: grammar

What is the verb tense for saying that a task must start sometime in the past and be completed at the present moment? For example, to say that the temperature must be maintained at 30 degrees from 2 hours ago up until now, can I use 'must have been' like in "By now, the temperature must have been maintained at 30 degrees."?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's not feasible to say now that something must be started two hours earlier than now (or * two hours ago*)

There are various options:

> The temperature must be maintained at 30 degrees for exactly two hours.
>
> The temperature must be maintained at 30 degrees for two hours (before removing the contents)
>
> The temperature must be maintained at 30 degrees for no longer than two hours.
>
> Before proceeding, ensure that the temperature has been maintained at 30 degrees for two hours.

And so on!

Comment: I think the second and fourth examples are the best, since the following action is important in "up to/until now" examples. The third one seems wrong, since it indicates time <= 2 hours, not equal or greater than 2 hours.

Comment: @user3169 whichever is useful to you in what you want to say.